# jQuery and Javascript - Detect when iPad keyboard is closed

Tags: javascript, ipad

If have an event that fires when a user clicks outside of text field, which also automatically hides the iPad keyboard.

However, I want to also fire this function when a user closes the keyboard from the detected button on the keyboard itself, so the same effect is achieved when the user is done editing.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I'm KICKING myself. onblur does do this!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to listen for keyboard open/close in Javascript/Sencha?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241492/how-to-listen-for-keyboard-open-close-in-javascript-sencha)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rightly commented by Andre, this is actually done via `onblur`, and it works completely fine.