# How to hide floating button on keyboard open(Android/iOS)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one floating button on my website which is built in Reactjs. I want to hide that button whenever i'll open keyboard on phone.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241492/how-to-listen-for-keyboard-open-close-in-javascript-sencha
[DUPLICATE]

Comment: @KingKabyle next time hit the close button and then close as duplicate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to listen for keyboard open/close in Javascript/Sencha?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241492/how-to-listen-for-keyboard-open-close-in-javascript-sencha)

Comment: @Tschallacka No, it hides the button but when I close the keyboard, button doesn't appear. Button appears on body click.

Comment: @gurupalsingh There is an answer there that accounts for window.height. have you looked at that one? Don't always only look at the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Keyboard is opened when some input is focused. So you can handle it with `onFocus` event

```
onFocus = () => {
    this.setState({hiddenButton: true})
}
onBlur = () => {
    this.setState({hiddenButton: false})
}

render() {
    <React.Fragment>    
        {!this.state.hiddenButton ? <button>Click here</button> : null }
        <input 
            type='text'
            onFocus={ this.onFocus } 
            onBlur={ this.onBlur } 
            placeholder="Enter your text here."
        />
    <React.Fragment>
}
```

`onBlur` event is fired when you leave input

Hope this helps you

Comment: The OP asked whenever keyboard is opened. Could this be refactored to apply to any textarea/input/contenteditable=true?

Comment: but i want to hide the button when my keyboard is open and vise versa.

Comment: When `onFocus` event fires it sets state that button is hidden. In `render()` method if button is hidden it button is not rendered. So, button is hidden when keyboard is opened

Comment: It hides the button but when I close the keyboard, button doesn't appear. Button appears on body click.

Comment: @Tschallacka I think it's not possible without global event listened but since react adds and removes dom every time and new dom doesn't have listener and you should add it again which affects performance

Comment: @gurupalsingh how you close keyboard? clicking on another place yes? in that case keyboard loses focus and fires `onBlur` event, so button is visible